# Как отфильтровать элементы jsonb массива

Tags: массивы, postgresql, фильтрация, фильтр, jsonb

Вроде бы распространённая задача, но решения не могу найти...

В хранимой функции в PostgreSQL есть массив в JSONB, нужно удалить из него элемент по значению.
Например, `'[1,2,3,4,5]'` нужно превратить в `'[1,2,3,5]'`, т.е. удалить элемент со значением `4`.

Вроде бы должно подойти выражение `'$[*] ? (@ != 4)'::jsonpath`
А для строк, возможно, и такое `'$[*] ? (@ like_regex "^The")'`

Но как его применить?

Если записать

```
SELECT '[1,2,3,4,5]'::jsonb @? '$[*] ? (@ != 4)'::jsonpath
```

То получаю *true*, а если так

```
SELECT '[1,2,3,4,5]'::jsonb @@ '$[*] ? (@ != 4)'::jsonpath
```

получаю *null*

Как получить новый jsonb-массив с отфильтрованными значениями?

*PS Есть вариант решения через такую громоздкую конструкцию, но это из пушки по воробьям:*

```
SELECT array_to_json(
    array(
        SELECT el FROM jsonb_array_elements('[1,2,3,4,5]') AS el WHERE el @? '$[*] ? (@ != 4)'
    )
) AS result;
```

Comment: А нету удаления из массива числа по значению. Вот удаление строкового значения - есть... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f33c97e729396d596904aa63a3f5bc65

Comment: Н-да, очень печально с числами. И операции обратной конкатенации массив нет... Значит будем работать с тем что есть, и думать как оптимизировать.